# MXNet - what is python equivalent of getting scala's mxnet networkExecutor.gradDict("data")

Tags: python, scala, mxnet

Trying to understand some Scala's code on network training in MXNet.

I believe you can access gradient on the executor in Scala by calling `networkExecutor.gradDict("data")`, what would be equivalent of it in Python MXNet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `grad_dict` in executor?  It returns a dictionary representation of the gradient arrays.

Comment: I think I've found a way to do it with existing API by calling get_input_grads, that are being computed after a call to do back propagation. It doesn't work by a key, but it will return an array of gradients consistent with the data input objects. http://mxnet.io/api/python/module.html#mxnet.module.BaseModule.get_input_grads